# How can I install GNU IceCat on a Debian-based system?

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, wayland, pureos, gnu-icecat

[GNU IceCat](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/) is the primary target for the [LibreJS extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/), making it a stable platform for running that extension.

So, I'd like to install Ice Cat on my Debian-based systems (running Debian, Ubuntu and PureOS). How can I do this? I'm happy to do crazy things up to and including using the Guix package manager, as long as I can launch the browser in a regular GNOME/Wayland session.

Comment: consider https://askubuntu.com/a/830386/7146

Comment: To my knowledge GNU Icecat is not maintained anymore. You only get ancient versions with known security issues. I have adjusted the build scripts for some newer builds but they need much more work for the newest versions of Mozilla Firefox. Building Icecat with such a script is a cumbersome and lengthy process.

Answer (score 5):

Download the latest version from [`ftp.gnu.org`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/) unpack it then create a symlink to run Icecat from the terminal:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/52.6.0/icecat-52.6.0.en-US.gnulinux-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar xvf icecat-52.6.0.en-US.gnulinux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s $PWD/icecat/icecat-bin /usr/bin/icecat
icecat
```

Using the guix pacakge manager:

```
$ guix package -i icecat
```

The binary should be set under `/home/$USER/.guix-profile/bin/icecat`. (see [3.2 Invoking guix package](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-package.html)).Assuming `guix` is correctly configured and the `$USER/.guix-profile/bin` is in your `$PATH` , you can start the browser from the terminal through:

```
$ icecat
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sparky](https://sparkylinux.org) and [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) already contains the .deb package of icecat.

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://sparkylinux.org/repo/sparkylinux.gpg.key

echo 'deb http://sparkylinux.org/repo testing main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sparky.list
```

or

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://packages.trisquel.info/trisquel/trisquel-archive-signkey.gpg

echo 'deb http://packages.trisquel.info/trisquel/ flidas-updates main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trisquel.list
```

### Notes

- If you wanna use with older distribution, then look at trisquel distro names which is the closest for yours.
- **WARNING:** This may also update existing packages, install new packages or suggest removing important packages (for example with `apt dist-upgrade`). Note, though, that it will not automatically remove packages.

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU Guix](https://guix.gnu.org/) package manager is a great way to get IceCat on any GNU/Linux distribution. Download and install Guix, then run: `guix install icecat`.

Guix also has a whole lot of other relatively new versions of software, so can be a great way to install packages such as NodeJS on top of stable versions of Debian.